# Javascript: Expand element when clicked, but shrink the relative elements?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to emulate Javascript 30's Flex Panel Image Gallery, but without using Flexbox.

Basically, we have a group of divs positioned next to each other. When one is clicked, the others shrink.

I can't figure out how to select the relative unclicked elements, to add the `.shrink` class.

Below are the markup. Thanks in advance!

**sorry for stacking the div's together -- it's to avoid the whitespaces..

```js
var panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

panels.forEach(function(panel) {
  panel.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}

.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 30%;
}

.panel1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.panel2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.active {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 40%;
}

.shrink {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 8.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"
  ><div class="panel1 panel">Red</div
  ><div class="panel2 panel">Green</div
  ><div class="panel3 panel">Blue</div
></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every non-clicked div should shrink, then add the `active` to the one that was clicked and remove the `shrink` from it. 
 Then loop through your panels, and for each one that isn't the one that was clicked, do the opposite.

```js
var panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

function togglePanels()
{  
        this.classList.add("active");
        this.classList.remove("shrink");
        for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i ++)
        {
     var panelToToggle = panels[i];
         if (panelToToggle !== this)
          {
           panelToToggle.classList.add("shrink")
            panelToToggle.classList.remove("active");
          }
        }
}

panels.forEach(function(panel){
    panel.addEventListener("click", togglePanels);
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}

.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 30%;
}

.panel1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.panel2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.active {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 40%;
}

.shrink {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 8.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel1 panel">Red</div><div class="panel2 panel">Green</div><div class="panel3 panel">Blue</div>  
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**  I just looked at the flex panel on the site you mention and one thing missing from the above is, if you click an expanded div, it resets all to normal.  To do that, you just have to check if the clicked div has `active` and if so, strip both classes from all panels.  Not sure if that's part of your requirement or not but, if so, here's how.

```js
var panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

function resetPanels()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i ++)
    {
   var panelToToggle = panels[i];
      panelToToggle.classList.remove("shrink");
      panelToToggle.classList.remove("active");
    }
}

function expandPanel(panelToExpand)
{
   panelToExpand.classList.add("active");
    panelToExpand.classList.remove("shrink");
    for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i ++)
    {
   var panelToToggle = panels[i];
      if (panelToToggle !== panelToExpand)
      {
        panelToToggle.classList.add("shrink")
        panelToToggle.classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
}

function togglePanels()
{  
 if (this.classList.contains("active"))
  {
  resetPanels();   
  }
  else
  {
   expandPanel(this);
  }
}

panels.forEach(function(panel){
    panel.addEventListener("click", togglePanels);
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}

.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 30%;
}

.panel1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.panel2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.panel3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.active {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 40%;
}

.shrink {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 8.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel1 panel">Red</div><div class="panel2 panel">Green</div><div class="panel3 panel">Blue</div>  
</div>
```